# How to write an abstract for a math paper?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

How would you go about writing an abstract for a Math paper? I know that an abstract is supposed to "advertise" the paper. However, I do not really know how to get started. Could someone tell me how they go about writing an abstract?

Comment: I think the abstract is supposed to summarize, not advertise the paper.

Comment: "The key to writing a good abstract is in formulating your theorems." --- http://www.impan.pl/EN/PubHouse/writing.pdf

Comment: Step #1: write a math paper.

Comment: Why is my question on hold as off topic? Similar questions such as [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1243/how-to-write-math-well?rq=1] on mathematical writing have been asked.

Comment: See discussion on meta: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2337

Answer (score 55, accepted):

1. Avoid notation if possible.  Notation makes it really hard to search electronically.
2. Put the subject in context, e.g., "In a recent paper, T. Lehrer introduced the concept of left-bifurcled rectangles.  He conjectured no such rectangles exist when the number of bifurcles $n$ is odd."
3. State your results, in non-technical language, if possible.  "In this paper we show the existence of left-bifurcled rectangles for all prime $n$."
4. Mention a technique, if there is a new one:  "Our methods involve analytic and algebraic topology of locally euclidean metrizations of infinitely differentiable Riemannian manifolds".
5. Never, ever, ever, cite papers in the bibliography by giving citation numbers; the abstract is an independent entity that should stand on its own.

Comment: Bozhe moi! (and yes, this is a good answer)

Comment: @ToddTrimble I saw what you did there!

Comment: @DavidRoberts You didn't see me plagiarize!

Answer (score 18):

Jeffrey has made a good list.  I'll add one:

A major purpose of an abstract is to help interested people find your paper when they search for a topic. To that end, if there are multiple names in use for the concepts in the paper, I recommend that you try to mention them all, even if you have to write "also known as ...".

Answer (score 15):

One thing that I have been taught to do in the body of a paper, but which may also make sense in an abstract is to state an easily-understood interest-piquing corollary of the main result "As a special case of our results, we demonstrate the existence of infinitely many integer solutions to the equation $x^3-y^2=17xy$".